# Parse string representation of dictionary to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

Slightly different use case than this post:
[Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

The difference being I am reading in from an excel spreadsheet so my string looks like this:

```
'{numerator: BV, denominator: Price}'
```

I don't have quotation marks around the keys or values. Wondering if there is some easy way to convert this into a dictionary. The usage of ast won't work I don't think.

I've done this, but I doubt this is the best way. Any suggestions?

```
test_params = '{numerator: BV, denominator: Price}'
comma_split = test_params.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split(",")

reconstructed_params = {}

for i in comma_split:
    splitted = i.split(":")
    splitted[0] = splitted[0].strip()
    splitted[1] = splitted[1].strip()
    reconstructed_params[splitted[0]] = splitted[1]

print(reconstructed_params)

{'numerator': 'BV', 'denominator': 'Price'}
```

A nice easy way would be great. There will also be times where my values are lists, but one thing at a time I suppose.

Comment: If it doesn't conform to any sort of established standard, then it's highly unlikely there'll be an "easy" way to do it. It'll have to be something like you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te quotes are here to protect the keys & values from other quotes, colons, braces, etc. Now, if keys are values are alphanumeric, you could apply a regular expression to *add* the quotes, then use `ast.literal_eval`

```
import re,ast

d = ast.literal_eval(re.sub('(\w+)',r'"\1"','{numerator: BV, denominator: Price}'))

>>> type(d)
<class 'dict'>
>>> d
{'denominator': 'Price', 'numerator': 'BV'}
```

This solution is fairly generic with the hypothesis taken, as it can decode nested dictionaries as well.

Comment: This is nice, solves my issue and other use cases. Thanks a lot!